# My MASM code shows 3 errors after debugging, but I do not know how to fix them. Can someone help me?

Tags: debugging, masm, masm64

```
;programul citeste de la tastatura doua numere intregi si le afiseaza.
.386            ;folosim instructiuni cu operanzi pe 32 biti
.MODEL FLAT, C  ;memoria este organizata liniar si conventia de apel a functiilor este cea din C
.STACK 100h     ;dimensunea stivei alocate
printf  PROTO arg1:ptr BYTE, printlist:VARARG   
scanf   PROTO arg2:ptr BYTE, inputlist:VARARG   ;prototipurile functiilor printf si scanf
.DATA
format1 BYTE    "%s",0
format2 BYTE    "%d",0
format3 BYTE    "%s %04d si %04d",10,0
mesaj1  BYTE    "Introduceti numerele:",0Ah,0
mesaj2  BYTE    "num1=",0
mesaj3  BYTE    "num2=",0
mesaj4  BYTE    0Ah,"Numerele sunt: ",0
num1    SDWORD  ?       ;sdword=signed double word --> numar de 32 de biti cu semn; echivalentul int
num2    SDWORD  ?       
.CODE
main PROC
;printf("%s","Introduceti numerele:\n");
INVOKE printf, ADDR format1, ADDR mesaj1  
;printf("%s","num1=");
;scanf("%d",&num1);
;printf("%s","num2=");
;scanf("%d",&num2);
;printf("%s %d si %d\n","\nNumerele sunt:",num1,num2);
INVOKE  printf, ADDR format1,ADDR mesaj2
INVOKE  scanf, ADDR format2,ADDR num1
INVOKE  printf, ADDR format1,ADDR mesaj3
INVOKE  scanf, ADDR format2,ADDR num2
INVOKE  printf, ADDR format3, ADDR mesaj4, num1, num2
ret
main ENDP 
END
```

After I press debug, i have 3 errors:
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _printf referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _scanf referenced in function _main
1>LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mainCRTStartup

I also wanted to add that I selected masm from Builder Dependencies and I added the libraries msvcrt.lib and legacy_stdio_definitions.lib in Linker Input. Do you know what can be the problem?

Comment: not after debugging but in build step. add *msvcrt.lib* or *libcmt.lib* to linker input

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked now, I thought i added them there already!

Answer (score -1):

As @RbMn pointed out:
Add msvcrt.lib and/or libcmt.lib to the linker search path.